# Stored procedure result for combobox failing to bind

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures, data-binding, combobox

i have this code, what I'm doing is executing a StoredProcedure, that simply selects 2 fields (ID, Name) and then i want to populate a combobox with the data. Here's my code...

```
   Using con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sqlAdp As New SqlDataAdapter
        con.Open()

        cmd.CommandText = "sp_RData"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Accounting")
        cmd.Connection = con
        sqlAdp.SelectCommand = cmd
        sqlAdp.Fill(ds)

        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    End Using
```

My stored procedure is very simple, goes like this....

```
Select ID, Name from tblRData where Name = @Name
```

@Name is obviously the parameter I'm trying to pass.

What happens is on Combobox1.ValueMember ="ID" it says "Cannot bind to the new display member."

Anyone know why? Is this the best way to populate a combobox with data from stored procedure? Wondering if this will be bulletproof, I don't see it not, since many of the comboboxes would be populated on form_load, just wondering if there's a better way of doing this. Just getting into vb.net from the wonderful world of VB6.

Comment: Try `ds.Tables(0)` as your `.DataSource`

Comment: @Jinx88909 - this seems to work. Is this the proper way of doing this? Loading comboboxes

Comment: You dont need a DataSet nor a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable and since you are just starting with NET, you might want to get in the habit of using Add rather than AddWithValue

Comment: I'm just trying to find the proper way of getting data from SP and populating a combobox with it. Although I'm a beginner, I do need to help with this app and need it to be bulletproof and done properly.

Comment: Contrary to the name, a DataSet doesnt store data - it is a handy container for multiple datatables.  So, building a temp datasource you dont need those things.  You should also dispose of the DbCommand object

Comment: You could declare a `DataTable` rather than a `DataSet` and then use `dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)` where `dt` is the `DataTable` variable. That's off top of my head.

Comment: @Jinx88909 DataTable seems to do the job too. The only annoying thing is you have to each time set it to .selectedindex=-1 otherwise it shows the first value from the datatable

Comment: ^^^ which is how the answer to your last question shows it being done

Comment: @Plutonix - i understand. Yes that's the way I did it thank to you. This was working with a Stored Procedure and I found a different article showing how it sould be done.

Comment: @Plutonix my question is- is this how this would be done properly? If someone has a different and more proper way of doing this, please post as answer and I'll happily accept it.

Comment: The natural behavior for a CBO is to have something selected, like a logical default.  So often you will add an order by clause to put that one at the top so the user doesnt have to do anything unless they want other than the default.  Makes it easier for them to compose a valid 'document'

Comment: Since many of those things ought to be disposed, I would use only as many as needed.  For instance you dont need a Command object and a DataAdapter:  `myDa = New SqkDataAdapter(sql_query, dbCon)` elides the command object.  Since you can fill a DT from a Command, I tend to use that instead.  A DataAdapter will do much, much more than fill a table, so unless I will be persisting one, I'd skip it.

Comment: @plutonix would you be able to post a complete example as answer and ill accept it. Thank you! I feel like you will be one of the people answering a lot of my vb.net questions in the future!

Comment: A "complete" example of everything would be pretty long.  Some tidbits on more economical code is provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing really "wrong" with the code is:

```vb
ComboBox1.DataSource = ds
```

Contrary to the name, a `DataSet` does not contain data, but is a collection of `DataTable` objects where the data resides, so:

```vb
ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

The code can be shorter and more efficient though:

```vb
Using con As New SqlConnection(sConnection),
     cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_RData")

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "Accounting"

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
End Using
```

- DataAdapters, DBCommand object as well as a few others should be disposed after use.  As a rule anything which implements a `Dispose()` method should be used in a `Using` block.  The code above "stacks" the Connection and Command object into one `Using` block mainly to reduce indentation.
- A DataAdapter is a very powerful thing.  It can store the connection and all the SQL to Add, Insert, Update and Delete from a single base table. Since you *can* fill a `DataTable` using a `DbCommand` object, it is a little simpler and uses fewer 'things' to get the job done.  With some providers and very large data sets, an adapter is faster, but the amount is not enough to worry about.
- Prefer `Add` to `AddWithValue` when working with Parameters.  The later requires the DB Provider to infer the data type from the data passed, which can fail in some situations.

The code above fills a local `DataTable` which then goes out of scope.  That may be fine, but given the WHERE clause maybe not.  If you later will (re)fill the CBO with names from "Janitorial" there is an easier way:

- Declare a form/class level `DataTable` so you can reference it elsewhere
- Drop the WHERE clause and fill it with ALL the names (e.g. "SELECT Id, Name FROM Departments").

Change the filter as needed:

```vb
dtDepts.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Name = '{0}", thisDept)
```

The View restricts what is shown to "Management" or "Secretarial" depending on what you want.  The CBO bound to the table is automatically updated.